# How to shift element an int left in an array then adding a number to the end?

Tags: java, arrays

So far what I have shifts each element to the left one, which I want to do. But I need to replace the end int with a 0 instead of duplicating it.

If it looked like [1,2,3,4,5] the output would be [2,3,4,5,0]

This is what I have so far

```
public static void shiftLeft ( int[] A){
    System.arraycopy(A,1,A,0,A.length - 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
}
```

Comment: `A[A.length -1] = 0` ?

Comment: FYI - If this is a school assignment, then you'll probably get the minimal amount of credit, if any.

Comment: @ScaryWombat well, it's so short you'd have to write some prose around it, but, that's it.. just put that as answer I guess.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - I can't concentrate now, I am still thinking of *crispybacon* hmmmm